# Value of $x$ where the tangent line is horizontal

Tags: derivatives

Find the value of $x$ where the tangent line to the curve $y=2xe^{-x}$ is horizontal. I need your help please...

Comment: What have you done so far on the problem?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Why is it sufficient to set the derivative equal to $0$ and solve?

Comment: since the derivative is the slope of the tangent line, equating it to 0 means that there is no slope at all (horizontal line has no slope)

Comment: i dont know how to simplify the derivative in the problem so i cant find the value of x

Comment: @Alice1997 What _is_ the derivative? Isn't it the sum of two terms? Do those terms have something in common?

Comment: @Alice1997: Notice that $e^{-x}>0$ for all $x$...

Comment: @Alice1997 So you're looking for the derivative of $y=2xe^{-x}$.

Comment: @Arthur i don't know... 2?

Comment: Are you aware of the product rule? (this is what you need) @Alice

Comment: @bluesh34 yeah. i tried getting the derivative and this is what i got

f'(x)=2x(e^-x)(-1)+0+2(1)(e^-x)
     =-(2xe^-x)+(2e^-x)

Comment: Well your answer is correct, although you don't really need the 0 in your initial calculation: consider it as the product of $2x$ and $e^{-x}$. Anyway, the next step is to factorise your answer, so that it's easier to see which value of $x$ makes it 0. Can you factorise the expression?